# Removing sources from sources.list doesn't work

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I had recently upgraded to php 5.4 but it was not working for me so I thought I'd remove php 5.4 and re-install php 5.3.

I uninstalled php5.4, removed the dotdeb sources from sources.list file, ran `apt-get update`, reinstalled php5, but it still installed php 5.4 from dotdeb, instead of using original debian repositories.

Here's what `dpkg -l | grep php` returns

```
# dpkg -l | grep php
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                 5.4.4-15                     server-side                                                                                        , HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
rc  libapache2-mod-php5filter           5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            server-side                                                                                        , HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
rc  libapache2-mod-suphp                0.7.1-1                      Apache2 mod                                                                                        ule to run php scripts with the owner permissions
rc  php-pear                            5.3.3-7+squeeze15            PEAR - PHP                                                                                         Extension and Application Repository
ii  php5                                5.4.4-15                     server-side                                                                                        , HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
rc  php5-cgi                            5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            server-side                                                                                        , HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                            5.4.4-15                     command-lin                                                                                        e interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                         5.4.4-15                     Common file                                                                                        s for packages built from the php5 source
rc  php5-curl                           5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            CURL module                                                                                         for php5
rc  php5-gd                             5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            GD module f                                                                                        or php5
rc  php5-imagick                        5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            imagick mod                                                                                        ule for php5
rc  php5-imap                           5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            IMAP module                                                                                         for php5
rc  php5-intl                           5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            internation                                                                                        alisation module for php5
rc  php5-mcrypt                         5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            MCrypt modu                                                                                        le for php5
rc  php5-mysql                          5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            MySQL modul                                                                                        e for php5
rc  php5-mysqlnd                        5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            MySQL modul                                                                                        e for php5 (Native Driver)
rc  php5-pgsql                          5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            PostgreSQL                                                                                         module for php5
rc  php5-pspell                         5.4.16-1~dotdeb.0            pspell modu                                                                                        le for php5
rc  phpmyadmin                          4:3.4.11.1-2                 MySQL web a                                                                                        dministration tool
rc  suphp-common                        0.7.1-1                      Common file                                                                                        s for mod suphp
```

Comment: Check that there isn't a dotdeb file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`as well.

Comment: Check this out: `grep -R dotdeb /etc/apt`

Answer (score 1):

"rc" means the configuration files exist. Type `apt-get remove php5 --purge` to completely get rid of it, then install from official.